# Python Crash Course Alien Invasion Score Resetting Issue

Tags: python

I am working on the alien invasion project in python crash course and am having trouble getting the score to reset after the play button is clicked to start a new game. Here are the bits of code that are supposed to do this function starting with the main file that runs the game.

```
#alien_invasion.py

def _check_play_button(self, mouse_pos):
           """Starts new game when player clicks play button"""
           button_clicked = self.play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
           if button_clicked and not self.stats.game_active:
               #Reset the game statistics
               self.settings.initialize_dynamic_settings()
               self.stats.game_active = True
               self.sb.prep_score()
               self.sb.prep_level()
               self.sb.prep_ships()
               
               #Get rid of any remaining aliens and bullets.
               self.aliens.empty()
               self.bullets.empty()
               
               #create a new fleet and center the ship
               self._create_fleet()
               self.ship.center_ship()
               
               #Hide Mouse cursor
               pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

and next the prep_score function which is supposed to reset the score when called in the above section of code

```
def prep_score(self):
        """Turn the score into a rendered image"""
        rounded_score = round(self.stats.score, -1)
        score_str = "{:,}".format(rounded_score)
        self.score_image = self.font.render(score_str, True,
                self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)
        
        #Display score at top right of the screen
        self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
        self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.score_rect.top = 20
```

Any idea why this is happening, any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the minimum reproducible example?

Comment: You said the prep_score() function "is supposed to reset the score". It doesn't do that, it "turns the score into a rendered image". Where is the actual value of the score defined? Where is it updated? That's what you need to look into.